# How to Create calendar control in Excel cell using closedXML dll and c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, closedxml

We have Download excel template option in our asp.net web application. In that excel template sheet, We should show the calendar control on one of the column to select the date & time values in that column cell. We have done drop down control into cell but don't know how to insert the calendar control into cell via Pragmatically.

Thanks,
Kavin.S

Comment: Form controls are supported in ClosedXML.

Comment: @FrancoisBotha How to insert the calendar control into cell using c#.
Thanks.